# OrmLite Android, setting foreignAutoRefresh to true results in join (self join) query?

Tags: android, ormlite

Using ORMLite under Android, when you set `foreignAutoRefresh` to true, does this result in join query or does ORMLite issue two queries one after another -- the "main query" and call to foreign objects `dao.refresh`?  I mean is this a dependent subquery or to two queries are sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) documentation from the [`foreignAutoRefresh` javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#foreignAutoRefresh%28%29):

> Set this to be true (default false) to have a foreign field automagically refreshed when an object is queried. This will *not* automagically create the foreign object but when the object is queried, a **separate database call** will be made to load of the fields of the foreign object via an internal DAO. The default is to just have the ID field in the object retrieved and for the caller to call refresh on the correct DAO.

The bolding is mine.  ORMLite does not do any JOINs at this time but issues a separate database query for any of the auto-refresh and other operations.